# IP Address not obtained in java

Tags: java

This code used to return my local ip address as 192.xxx.x.xxx but now it is returning 127.0.0.1 . Please help me why the same code is returning different value. Is there something that I need to watch at linux OS.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.net.*;

public class GetOwnIP
{
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    try{
      InetAddress ownIP=InetAddress.getLocalHost();
      System.out.println("IP of my system is := "+ownIP.getHostAddress());
    }catch (Exception e){
      System.out.println("Exception caught ="+e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

127.0.0.1 is the loopback adapter - it's a perfectly correct response to the (somewhat malfomed) question "what is my IP address?"

The problem is that there are *multiple* correct answers to that question.

EDIT: The docs for `getLocalHost` say:

> If there is a security manager, its
>   checkConnect method is called with the
>   local host name and -1 as its
>   arguments to see if the operation is
>   allowed. If the operation is not
>   allowed, an InetAddress representing
>   the loopback address is returned.

Is it possible that the change in behaviour is due to a change in permissions?

EDIT: I believe that `NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces` is what you need to enumerate all the possibilities. Here's an example which doesn't show virtual addresses, but works for "main" interfaces:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws Exception // Just for simplicity
    {
        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> ifaces = 
               NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
             ifaces.hasMoreElements(); )
        {
            NetworkInterface iface = ifaces.nextElement();
            System.out.println(iface.getName() + ":");
            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> addresses =
                   iface.getInetAddresses();
                 addresses.hasMoreElements(); )
            {
                InetAddress address = addresses.nextElement();
                System.out.println("  " + address);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(I'd forgotten just how awful the `Enumeration<T>` type is to work with directly!)

Here are the results on my laptop right now:

```
lo:
  /127.0.0.1
eth0:
  /169.254.148.66
eth1:
eth2:
ppp0:
  /10.54.251.111
```

(I don't think that's giving away any *hugely* sensitive information :)

If you know which network interface you want to use, call `NetworkInterface.getByName(...)` and then look at the addresses for that interface (as shown in the code above).

Comment: In the loop above, you could also simply skip over the loopback by checking NetworkInterface#isLoopback().

Comment: Why is there a slash before the IP address?

Comment: @Matías It is the Java toString of an InetAddress object use address.getHostAddress() to get just the dot-separated numbers.

Answer (score 6):

When you use InetAddress.getLocalHost() you are not guaranteed to get a particular interface, ie. you could receive the loopback (127) interface or a connected one.

In order to ensure you always get an external interface, you should use the java.net.NetworkInterface class. The static getByName(String) class will give you the interface with the defined name (such as "eth0"). Then you can use the getInetAddresses() function to obtain the IP addresses (could be just one) bound to that interface.

```
NetworkInterface ni = NetworkInterface.getByName("eth1");
ni.getInetAddresses();
```

Answer (score 2):

Check your /etc/host file. If you put 127.0.0.1 first, it will return this as result.

The correct way to get the ip address is to use `NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()` and run `getInetAddresses()` on each of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()` method to retrieve an `Enumeration` of all of the network interfaces for your system.

For each of the `NetworkInterface` instances, you can then use the `getInetAddresses()` method to retrieve an `Enumeration` of all of the `InetAddress` instances associated with the network interface.

Finally, you can use the `getHostAddress()` method on each `InetAddress` instance to retrieve the IP address in textual form.

Answer (score -1):

This is because you have a line in /etc/hosts like
127.0.0.1 localhost
you need to have
192.xxx.xxx.xxx localhost

Though please note that this would be very bad as to solve a code issue you should not modify linux config files. Not only is it not right (and risks breaking some other network aware apps on your linux box) it will also not work anywhere else (unless the admins of those boxes are also like minded).

javadoc for InetAddress.getLocalHost(); read "....an InetAddress representing the loopback address is returned." so it appears that the implementation of getLocalHost() is incorrect
on your UNIX and WIN boxes. The loopback address is nearly allways 127.0.0.1

Found this comment
"A host may have several IP addresses and other hosts may have to use different addresses to reach it. E.g. hosts on the intranet may have to use 192.168.0.100, but external machines may have to use 65.123.66.124. If you have a socket connection to another host you can call
Socket.getLocalAddress() to find out which local address is used for the socket."