# How can I find all locally bound IP addresses in Java?

Tags: java, networking, ip-address

I would like to have all locally bound IP addresses, basically an array of java.net.InetAddress. I know I can call InetAddress.getAllByName() with the host name, but I was wondering if there is a more direct way that doesn't involve DNS and/or knowledge of the host name.

Comment: Take a look at this threat: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062041/ip-address-not-obtained-in-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`java.net.NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()` will give you an enumeration of the available network interfaces. You can then invoke `getInetAddresses()` on each NetworkInterface to get the addresses bound to this interface.