# How to list all computers in network?

Tags: java, networking, rmi

For a small java game I made, I would like to be able to play it with two computers in the same (home) network. I think I will use RMI and am now trying with computer on ipaddress 192.168.2.3.
I know I can search for a registry on this ipaddress on my other computer at 192.168.2.6, but I would like to show a list of all ipaddresses in the network my computer is connected with. Prefferably only if they actually host a game.

Now I tried some questions here on stackoverflow:

- [How to enumerate IP addresses of all enabled NIC cards from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494465)
- [How can I find all locally bound IP addresses in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827270)
- [How to get a list of IP connected in same network (subnet) using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345857)
- [Why does InetAddress.isReachable return false, when I can ping the IP address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922543)

,but I don't think I need all my computer network interfaces and InetAddress.isReachable() always seem to result to false (even though I can ping via cmd and I have firewall turned off) and calling a commandline

"ping -n 1 192.168.2.i" for all i, where 0<=i<=255,

always exits normal, so it results always in true.

What is the best way to get a list of ipaddresses of computers in the same network as the computer the JVM runs on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the linked answers, you should be able to filter the available interfaces down to a few possible options (i.e. interfaces that are up, no loopback, have an IPv4 address, etc.).

To discover game hosts, you can do something like the following.

- Let the game hosts listen for UDP broadcasts on a specific port.
- Let the clients send out a UDP broadcast to the broadcast address of each of the remaining interfaces from above. The broadcast address can be determined by `getBroadcast()` in class `InterfaceAddress`.
- The host replies, to let the client know it is waiting. When using UDP, the hosts IP is in the received `DatagramPacket`. When using TCP, the hosts IP can be determined from the `Socket`.
- Then the client can use the address of the host to establish a direct connection and/or set up RMI.

Edit: I found [this blog post](http://michieldemey.be/blog/network-discovery-using-udp-broadcast/), which includes code that does more or less what I described.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. I thought the interfaces only give the current computer's ipaddress(es), but in your second bullet you imply that I can get the ipaddresses of other computers. Could you give an (link to) example which shows how I can get those other computer's ipaddresses?

Comment: @LiontackLightning Not it doesn't. It says send to the *broadcast address* of the NIC. The NIC is still local.

Comment: @LiontackLightning You can get the broadcast address from the local interfaces. A broadcast reaches all computers on the network. You don't need to know the specific destination address. I updated my post and included a link to an example.

Comment: @Prometheus The broadcast address I can connect through now always is '192.168.2.254', which is the router. But on one laptop the broadcast address is '0.0.0.0' and this laptop can't find any server. I can't find the fix for this laptop. Do you have suggestions for this?

Comment: All I can say is that those aren't broadcast addresses. Were they returned by the getBroadcast() method? Hard to say what went wrong without the code.