# How to get System IP using Java?

Tags: networking, java, netbeans

I am trying to create a Java program to retrieve my systems IP address using Java.
On the click of a button, the IP address is displayed is a text box.

[IP in java using Netbeans](https://picasaweb.google.com/110032752637088824628/SystemIPStackoverflow?authkey=Gv1sRgCPTNvLD3qbqRJw#5638314483328453106)

Now the problem is, everytime I use the code

```
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try {
        jTextField1.setText(Inet4Address.getLocalHost().toString());
    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
        jTextField1.setText("IP not found");
    }
}
```

It only retrieves my loopback IP and not the static IP which I have configured in Ubuntu which is of the range 192.16x.xxx.xxx
This piece of code works fine on my windows 7 but not on Ubuntu 11.04, I dont know why...!!!
I dont wanna use windows for developing applications or anything.

Just 2 questions I have

1. How do I retrieve my systems static IP ?
2. If java is cross-platform, why does this piece of code works well on windows & not on Ubuntu ?

Comment: The picture is in the link

https://picasaweb.google.com/110032752637088824628/SystemIPStackoverflow?authkey=Gv1sRgCPTNvLD3qbqRJw#5638314483328453106

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481865/how-to-get-ip-address-of-our-own-system-using-java

Answer (score 7):

Your problem looks very similar to [this one in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062041/ip-address-not-obtained-in-java), maybe the answer will help you ;)

Comment: yep, link you gave pretty much explains everything there is to know about this.

Comment: To summarize that question: A networked computer typically has _multiple_ IP addresses, all of them valid.