# Java applet only return 127.0.0.1

Tags: java, applet, ip-address

People I created a java applet to get the Local IP, enter this applet in a web page, but it only returns me the ip 127.0.0.1.
I tested some answers I found here on stackoverflow, but none worked.
Is there any way to get IP Local real?
I've seen it run on some sites.
Below is the code I made:

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
public class PegaIP extends JApplet {
    @Override
    public void init() {
        try {
            getAppletContext().showDocument (new URL("javascript:UpdateIP(\"" + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress() + "\")"));
        } catch (UnknownHostException | MalformedURLException e) {
            System.err.println("Ocorreu erro na criação da GUI");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't *"Error occurred in creating the GUI"* be *"Our attempt to snoop on your location failed, and we won't show the GUI"*?  What feature do these actions provide to the end user?  Would the end user be motivated enough to have that feature, that they would either a) allow trusted code to support the feature? b) answer questions accurately?

Comment: possible duplicate of [IP Address With Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11941059/ip-address-with-java)

Comment: If you connect to a (same origin) server, that will be able to tell you the IP address of the client, although it may well have goine through NAT.

Comment: @AndrewThompson is like I said earlier, I tested several of the responses here stackoverflow and none worked, you indicated this was one of them and unfortunately got the same result. How much the message I send to print, yet is only a test, not ready for the end user. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline do you have some docs or exemples for me? Like I sayd I'm a totaly noob in java...

Answer (score 1):

My guesses are that you need to allow the specific operation to work since you are inside an applet, documentation states:

> If there is a security manager, its checkConnect method is called with the local host name and -1 as its arguments to see if the operation is allowed. If the operation is not allowed, an InetAddress representing the loopback address is returned.

To test if it's true you should try it in a normal Java application, if 127.0.0.1 is not returned then the problem resided inside the security manager. You could try also by calling

```
public void checkConnect(String host, int port)
```

of the current security manager to see if it raises a `SecurityException`.

Read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/tour1/index.html) for more info about applets and their permissions.