# IP Address in Java on Linux

Tags: java, windows, linux, ip-address, inetaddress

So far I always used following to get my IP Address:

```
InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()
```

The above method works for Windows but on linux I always get `127.0.1.1` as my IP address.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062041/ip-address-not-obtained-in-java?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found some code on the Internet which should solve your problem:

```
String hostName = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();

InetAddress addrs[] = InetAddress.getAllByName(hostName);

String myIp = "UNKNOWN";
for (InetAddress addr: addrs) {
  System.out.println ("addr.getHostAddress() = " + addr.getHostAddress());
  System.out.println ("addr.getHostName() = " + addr.getHostName());
  System.out.println ("addr.isAnyLocalAddress() = " + addr.isAnyLocalAddress());
  System.out.println ("addr.isLinkLocalAddress() = " + addr.isLinkLocalAddress());
  System.out.println ("addr.isLoopbackAddress() = " + addr.isLoopbackAddress());
  System.out.println ("addr.isMulticastAddress() = " + addr.isMulticastAddress());
  System.out.println ("addr.isSiteLocalAddress() = " + addr.isSiteLocalAddress());
  System.out.println ("");

  if (!addr.isLoopbackAddress() && addr.isSiteLocalAddress()) {
    myIp = addr.getHostAddress();
  }
}
```

Source: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/Local.html

The basic difference to your code is that all ip-adresses are checked.

Answer (score 0):

Is your application using a security manager? getLocalHost will return the loopback address if it's unable to connect to your address.